# CakePHP and Wordpress on Nginx PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php-fpm, cakephp

I'm trying to configure both CakePHP and a wordpress blog on the same server.

CakePHP here: http://site.com/

Wordpress blog here: http://site.com/blog/

**What works:** The whole CakePHP app and going to /blog/.

**What doesn't work:** Going to /blog/permalink/. It gives a CakePHP 404 page.

The /blog/ works with or without the "# Blog config" below. How do I make /blog/permalink/ work? I'm used to working with Apache.

**edit:** It was suggested that my question is a duplicate of [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/478597/nginx-and-wordpress-permalinks-are-broken-if-blog-is-not-in-root) however if I use that solution or my solution (commented # Blog config) below it gives me a CakePHP 404 page. This means that /blog/permalink/ doesn't hit the wordpress's index.php.

```
upstream backend {
    server unix:/var/www/apps/appname/tmp/php.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    root    /var/www/apps/appname/public/app/webroot;
    index   index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_tokens off;

    access_log  /var/www/apps/appname/logs/access.log;
    error_log   /var/www/apps/appname/logs/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    rewrite_log on;

    # Blog config
    location /blog/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    # Not found this on disk? 
    # Feed to CakePHP for further processing!
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
        break;
    }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    # listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; # to support 404s for PHP files not found
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Static files.
    # Set expire headers, Turn off access log
    location ~* \favicon.ico$ {
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
    location ~ ^/(img|cjs|ccss)/ {
        access_log off;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~ ^/(php_status|php_ping)$ {
      fastcgi_pass backend;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files,
    # git & svn repositories, etc
    location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the accidental mark as duplicate. I misread your config on first reading and didn't realize that you'd already done what was in the answer there.

Comment: Ok... I'll let this one pass... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your problem. It rewrites all URLs, not just those destined for CakePHP. This is one of [the most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#check-if-file-exists).

```
    # Not found this on disk? 
    # Feed to CakePHP for further processing!
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
        break;
    }
```

This should be deleted and replaced with an equivalent `try_files` in your `location /` block (which you don't seem to have, so create one).

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! That seems to have worked perfectly. Thanks :)